# Out of memory while creating bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

How to scale this bitmap image am getting out of memory exception

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            return bitmap;
```

How to resolve this ?
The below error is am getting

> 05-07 13:13:30.329: E/dalvikvm-heap(17186): Out of memory on a
>   8294416-byte allocation. 05-07 13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-07 13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):
>   Process: com.example, PID: 17186 05-07 13:13:30.339:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17186): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 05-07
>   13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) 05-07
>   13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:819) 05-07
>   13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:796) 05-07
>   13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:763) 05-07
>   13:13:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(17186):    at
>   com.example.QRCode.encodeAsBitmap(QRCode.java:135)

Comment: You can try using createScaledBitmap() method from Bitmap and don´t use too large images....

Comment: Maybe your bitmap is too big. or you can try [largeheap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap), largeheap might help, but you should let the bitmap smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Load a scaled down version of that Bitmap into your memory. Doing a short Google research will guide you to this [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).
There they have this sample code:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Comment: In my case am generating qrcode its dynamic not from draw-able folder